# How to properly create template object of type T i.e. T result = T();

Tags: c++14

Hi I am trying to create an object of type T where T is a pointer via the use of T result = T(). But instead of calling the constructor it simply returns a null pointer.

Here is an example of some affected code:

```
template <class T>
    T readBlockchain(std::ifstream* stream) {
        T result = T(); // Result is null after this
        decltype(result->getLastBlock()) blkPtr = result->getLastBlock();
        auto blk = *blkPtr;
        decltype(result->getLastBlock()) lastBlock = &readBlock<decltype(blk)>(stream);
        if(!lastBlock->verify())
            return nullptr;
        unsigned long count = *readUnsignedLong(stream);
        unsigned long orphanCount = *readUnsignedLong(stream);
        std::map<std::string, decltype(blk)> blocks = std::map<std::string, decltype(blk)>();
        for(int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++){
            decltype(blk) block = readBlock<decltype(blk)>(stream);
            if(!block.verify())
                return nullptr;
            blocks.insert(std::make_pair(block.getHash(), block));
        }
        std::vector<Blockchain<decltype(blk)>*> orphanedChains = std::vector<Blockchain<decltype(blk)>*>();
        for(int i = 0; i < orphanCount - 1; i++){
            Blockchain<decltype(blk)>* orphan = &readOrphanedChain<Blockchain<decltype(blk)>>(stream);
            orphanedChains.push_back(orphan);
        }
        result->setLastBlock(lastBlock);
        result->setCount(count);
        result->setOrphanCount(orphanCount);
        result->setBlocks(blocks);
        result->setOrphanedChains(orphanedChains);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is `T`? If `T` is a pointer to something, `T()` default-creates a pointer, which will result in a `nullptr`. Use something like `using S = std::decay_t<T>; T result = new S;`.

Comment: Yes T is a pointer, I will edit the question

Comment: Why don't you templatize your method on the type the pointer points to and return a `T*`? That would be more transparent. `template <class T> T* readBlockchain (...) { T * result = new T; ... }`. Or, even better, create and return a  `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

Comment: So with `T result = T();`, you ask a default contructed pointer, so a `nullptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct. In order to generalize your `readBlockchain` correctly, you would want when `T` is a pointer to create a new object of `T` in the heap and when `T` is a concrete type to create a regular `T` object by calling the constructor of `T`. One solution would be to use the following specialization construct.

```
template<typename T>
struct CreateNew {
  template<typename... Args>
  static T apply(Args&&... args) { return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};

template<typename T>
struct CreateNew<T*> {
  template<typename... Args>
  static decltype(auto) apply(Args&&... args) { return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
```

That is, you could create a template class that takes a template argument `T` along with a specialization of that template class for pointers of type `T*`. Inside the primary template (e.g., static member function `apply`) you'll create objects of type `T` by calling the constructor of class `T` and inside the specialization you'll create heap objects of `T*` (Notice that in the specialization I return a `std::unique_ptr<T*>` for convenience).

Thus, your `readBlockChain` template function would become:

```
template <class T>
decltype(auto) readBlockchain(std::ifstream* stream) {
  auto result = CreateNew<T>::apply(/* T constructor arguments */);
  ...
  return result;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26879b8d94fd299c)

Comment: Thanks, ill try this later and let you know!